# Обьясните, почему здесь "так же" написано раздельно?

Tags: также

Почему в данном варианте написано раздельно? Ведь "также" можно заменить на "тоже",на "и" без потери смысла. Или здесь допустимы оба варианта написания в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Здесь **точно** передает смысл только один вариант:

Мы **внимательно** выслушиваем каждого пациента. И ценим, когда  пациент так же **внимательно** слушает своего врача.

В данном случай  ***ТАК*** указывает на **степень признака**, выраженного **наречием:** так внимательно, как и мы. ***ЖЕ*** — усилительная частица.

Сравнить: *Врач слушает вас, вы **также** должны слушать врача* (= и вы должны слушать врача)